# Missing PATH_INFO on Apache 2.4 / php5.6-fpm / proxy_fcgi

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm

I'm using Debian 9 with PHP-FPM `7.0.26-2` & `5.6.32-1` from repository deb.sury.org. The same configuration is working fine on a Debian 8 server with PHP-FPM `5.6.30`

- I've copied the `pool.d/user.conf` from that server.
- Both `php.ini` files are having `cgi.fix_pathinfo=1`.
- The parameter is also forced using `php_admin_value[cgi.fix_pathinfo] = 1`.
- Both servers uses this pool similarly from `<VirtualHost>` context with:

  ```
  ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/run/php/user.sock|fcgi://localhost/home/user/public_html
  ```

Now, there's an AJAX page that needs to read path from `PATH_INFO` (possibly `PATH_TRANSLATED`). However, while these variables have correct content on the Debian 8 server:

```
["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
string(14) "/path/ajax.php"
["ORIG_SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
string(25) "/path/ajax.php/para/meters"
["PATH_INFO"]=>
string(12) "/para/meters"
["PATH_TRANSLATED"]=>
string(34) "/home/user/public_html/para/meters"
```

They seem to work differently on the fresh Debian 9 + dub.sury.org:

```
["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
string(25) "/path/ajax.php/para/meters"
["PATH_TRANSLATED"]=>
string(22) "/home/user/public_html"
```

And the prameters `ORIG_SCRIPT_NAME` and `PATH_INFO` are completely missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the way I used the proxy_fcgi. As explained in the examples for [`mod_proxy_fcgi`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html):

> You can also force a request to be handled as a reverse-proxy request,
>   by creating a suitable Handler pass-through. - - The benefit of this
>   form is that it allows the normal mapping of URI to filename to occur
>   in the server, and the local filesystem result is passed to the
>   backend. **When FastCGI is configured this way, the server can
>   calculate the most accurate `PATH_INFO`.**

So I replaced my

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/run/php/user.sock|fcgi://localhost/home/user/...
```

with a Handler & Worker:

```
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
            SetHandler  "proxy:unix:/run/php/user.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
    <Proxy "fcgi://localhost/" enablereuse=on max=10>
    </Proxy>
```

Now all the AJAX request are working fine.

**BONUS:** If some knows why the `ProxyPassMatch` was able to calculate the the `PATH_INFO` before on my Debian 8 / Apache 2.4.10 / PHP-FPM 5.6.30 but not with Debian 9, that would be awesome.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. `PATH_INFO` was not passed after I upgraded to Debian 9 and set my Apache config with ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$" "unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/var/www/"

Comment: I'm glad, if this was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

As it is decribed on:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html#env

The reason, why the ProxyPassMatch does not set the PATH_INFO is the following:

> **Environment Variables**
>
> In addition to the configuration directives that
>   control the behaviour of mod_proxy, there are a number of environment
>   variables that control the FCGI protocol provider:
>
> - **proxy-fcgi-pathinfo**:
>     When configured via ProxyPass or ProxyPassMatch,
>     mod_proxy_fcgi will not set the PATH_INFO environment variable. This
>     allows the backend FCGI server to correctly determine SCRIPT_NAME and
>     Script-URI and be compliant with RFC 3875 section 3.3. If instead you
>     need mod_proxy_fcgi to generate a "best guess" for PATH_INFO, set this
>     env-var. This is a workaround for a bug in some FCGI implementations.
>     This variable can be set to multiple values to tweak at how the best
>     guess is chosen (In 2.4.11 and later only):
>
>   - **first-dot**: PATH_INFO is
>       split from the slash following the first "." in the URL.
>   - **last-dot**:
>       PATH_INFO is split from the slash following the last "." in the URL.
>   - **full**: PATH_INFO is calculated by an attempt to map the URL to the local
>       filesystem.
>   - **unescape**: PATH_INFO is the path component of the URL,
>       unescaped / decoded.
>   - **any other value**: PATH_INFO is the same as the path
>       component of the URL. Originally, this was the only
>       proxy-fcgi-pathinfo option.

Comment: The answer can be improved telling how to declare that environment variable.